# Is adding some image for 'flavor' out of the rules?

Tags: discussion

I've been edited. Most of the things I can agree with, but one is sticking with me. https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/304585/revisions

The edit has a description that said 'While funny, the image didn't really add anything to the question other than a distraction.'

Yes, and? If I want to add an image to 'spice up' my post, and not just be a boring straight to the point question, can I? or is it frowned upon in some way?

To me, as long as you don't have to find the question through a paragraph of jokes, it should be fine?

Comment: Signal to noise. Is the picture helping your question? No? Then it doesn't belong. Remember, we hate fun here.

Comment: @Frank You don't speak for the community. I don't hate fun, especially if it's not *actively detracting*, which I don't feel that image is. It made me laugh and want to read the rest of the question

Comment: @cazc_941 Actually, considering the number of upvotes on both Frank's comment and the (accepted) answer, the community is in agreement - the picture doesn't add anything to the content of the question and doesn't need to be there.

Comment: @cacz Enough, Gnome. You disagree with me. I get it. You don't need to comment on each and every thing you disagree with.

Comment: Yeah you're probably right.  I do like fun though

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While I don't think there is a specific "rule" forbidding it, it is highly discouraged to add in things that distract from the question. We like to have a well curated set of questions and answers that can be easily read and understood. If a picture is needed to explain the question or answer, or helps to explain; then by all means, put the picture in there. But if the picture is just something that is funny and is only mildly related to the question or answer, don't include it as it only distracts and detracts from the information in the question or answer. It's not that we hate fun, we just like well written questions and answers more. Have your fun playing the game.